# Insert hyperlink with linkText at current caret position in richtextbox WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0, wpf-4.5

I want to insert a hyperlink with displayText into a richtextbox at the current caret position, I am displaying a popup window for the user to enter the linkURL and the linkText when the user clicks on the Ok button the hyperlink with the display text should be inserted at the current caret position in the RichTextBox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Test This Code

```
        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
        link.IsEnabled = true;
        link.Inlines.Add(" Microsoft ");
        link.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");

        var allRang = new TextRange(Rich.Document.ContentStart,Rich.Document.ContentEnd);
        if (allRang.Start.Parent is Run)
        {
            var run = allRang.Start.Parent as Run;
            var runBefore =
                           new Run(new TextRange(run.ContentStart, Rich.CaretPosition).Text);
            var runAfter =
                           new Run(new TextRange(Rich.CaretPosition, run.ContentEnd).Text);

            if (allRang.Start.Paragraph != null)
            {
                allRang.Start.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(runBefore);
                allRang.Start.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(link);

                allRang.Start.Paragraph.Inlines.Add(runAfter);
                allRang.Start.Paragraph.Inlines.Remove(run);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi M SH GOL,

Thanks for your reply but we are using Third party tools now for HTML Editing so we stopped looking for a solution for this issue, In my free time I will try to test the code you have provided and inform you about it.

Thanks,
Abdul Mateen.

Comment: Hi M SH GOL, 

The hyperlink inserts correctly first time but after that it doesn't, Suppose after Microsoft hyperlink I add it again It's coming like this  Microsoft   Microsoft   Microsoft  Microsoft  

Thanks.